# Updating data to a table using select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 4 tables:

```
**appdetail** 
id, alocation

**alocation**
id, appdetail

**place**
id, name

**location_place**
alocation, place
```

location_place.alocation points to alocation.id
location_place.place points to place.id

I want to copy the values of location_place.alocation to appdetail.alocation. I tried the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963158/815859. However, I am getting "SQL command not properly ended" error. My query is

```
update appdetail set 
alocation =i.alocation
from 
(select lp.alocation
from location_place lp,
alocation apl,
appdetail ad
where
lp.alocation = apl.id
and 
apl.id in (547,294)
and
ad.id = apl.appdetail
)i
where appdetail.alocation = i.alocation
```

The DBFiddle is at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8SB3tHxWVY7NbCyzpKLhRG/4

Comment: Question is confusing. Can you please share sample data for each table and expected output?

Comment: I have updated the question with a DBFiddle link. Please check.

Comment: What is expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MERGE INTO` for it:

```
MERGE INTO appdetail AD
USING (
SELECT ID, appdetail
  FROM LOCATION L
  JOIN location_place LP
  ON (LP.LOCATION = L.ID)
-- WHERE L.id in (547,294) 
) I ON (AD.ID = I.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET AD.LOCATION = I.ID;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f02db2c1eb49ab6b0adb592f3cd61e58)

Cheers!!

**-- UPDATE --**

as per requirement changed and communicated as in comment,
You can use the following query:

```
MERGE INTO appdetail AD
USING (
SELECT ID, appdetail, LP.PLACE
  FROM LOCATION L
  JOIN location_place LP
  ON (LP.LOCATION = L.ID) 
) I ON (AD.ID = I.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET AD.LOCATION = I.PLACE;
```

[db<>fiddle demo updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7448806514fc2822f6b21184ea94a67c)

Cheers!!

Comment: I stated the requirement incorrectly. What i am looking for is inserting the value of LOCATION_TABLE.PLACE (which is linked to place.id) to APPDETAIL.LOCATION.

Answer (score 0):

FROM is not part of the Oracle UPDATE syntax.

What I think you intended is this:

```
 update appdetail ad
 set ad.alocation = (select lp.alocation
                     from   location_place lp,
                            alocation apl
                      where lp.alocation  = apl.id
                      and   apl.id       in (547,294)
                      and   ad.id         = apl.appdetail )
```

Comment: Note: this is just a guess. If it doesn't work for you please **edit your question** to include some sample data and desired output derived from that sample.

Comment: I have updated the question with a DBFiddle link. Please check.